# why generating random sprites gives black screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have been trying the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i ++){
int amount = arc4random()%3;
SKSpriteNode *Obsticle;

for (i = 0; i < (amount+1); i++) {
        int position = arc4random()%2;
        int size = arc4random()%2;

        Obsticle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor purpleColor] size:CGSizeMake((size + 1)* self.scene.size.height/5, self.scene.size.height/5)];
        Obsticle.name = @"obsticle";
        Obsticle.position = CGPointMake(Obsticle.size.width/2 - self.scene.size.width/2 + position * self.scene.size.height/5, 2*self.currentY+self.scene.size.height/5);
        Obsticle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Obsticle.size];
        Obsticle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        [world addChild:Obsticle];
    }
    self.currentY += self.scene.size.height/5;
}
```

The code should generate various length block at random points on the screen. However, if I run the simulation on xcode, it shows black screen only ( I think it does not load because it does not display fps and node amount). Any ideas how to fix it or maybe you you now more effective way of making what I just tried to create?

Comment: Try using an actual device or resetting your simulator

Comment: log Obsticle.position, after setting it, to see whether it is drawing under the bounding of the screen. If it fine then show how you have initialize your world object..

Comment: I found a mistake. I have a little experience with objective c and used to work with python, where I could use the same name for loop iterations. I changed the name of iterand of the second for loop and it started to work.